# HTML Menu, php, highlight first item of its submenu item

Tags: php, html, arrays, function, menu

I'm searching for a solution for automatic highlightning top menu items.

Current situation looks like this:
I have default menu stored in a .txt file:

```
<li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MENU_1</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="submenu_1.php">Submenu_1</a></li>
    <li><a href="submenu_2.php">Submenu_2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">MENU_2</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu_1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="sub_submenu_1.php">Sub_Submenu_1</a></li>
        <li><a href="sub_submenu_2.php">Sub_Submenu_2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Submenu_2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="menu_3.php">MENU_3</a></li>
<li><a href="menu_4.php">MENU_4</a></li>
```

So, when the `submenu`, or `sub_submenu`, or whatever item is a current page, I need its very top `MENU_X` parent item to be highlighted (as only the `MENU_X` items are visible on my page top bar).

I made CSS style aplied to `MENU_X`, so when I set the top menu like:

```
<li class="current"><a href="#">MENU_1</a>
```

it's highlighted by the `.current` CSS style.

Now I'm searching for a PHP script which would do something like this (example only):

```
<?php
$currentPage = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$url_parts = Explode('/', $currentPage);
$current_php_file = $url_parts[count($url_parts) - 1];

$raw_menu = file_get_contents("menu.txt");

$current_menu_item = '<li><a href="' . $current_php_file . '">'

$top_menuitem_of_current_page = someFunctionToFindOut(); //need some script to find out

$highlighted_menu_item = '<li class="current"><a href="' . $top_menuitem_of_current_page . '">';
$ready_menu = str_replace($top_menuitem_of_current_page, $highlighted_menu_item, $raw_menu);
echo $ready_menu;
?>
```

The code above basically would do the trick, but I need to call some function `someFunctionToFindOut()` to find out what is the `$top_menuitem_of_current_page`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: No. This seems to highlight a current page. I need to highlight a very first menu containing the current page. Not current page or its parent.

Answer (score 1):

As nobody provided working solution, I would like to answer to my question:

```
include("menu.php");

$current_page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

$menu = "";

function menu_to_array($array, $found) {
    foreach($array as $key => $element){
        if(!is_array($element)){
            if($element == $current_page && !$found){
                $found = true;
                $menu .= "<li class='current'><a href='$element'>$key</a></li>";
            }else{
                $menu .= "<li><a href='$element'>$key</a></li>";
            }
        }else{ 
            if(found_current_page_in($element) && !$found){
                $menu .= "<li class='current'><a href='#'>$key</a><ul>" . menu_to_array($element, true) . "</ul></li>";
            }else{
                $menu .= "<li><a href='#'>$key</a><ul>" . menu_to_array($element, false) . "</ul></li>";
            }
        }
    }
    return $menu; 
}

function found_current_page_in($elem){
    foreach($elem as $key => $element){
        if(!is_array($element)){
            if($element == $current_page){
                return true;
            }
        }else{
            if(found_current_page_in($element)){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$highlighted_menu = menu_to_array($menu_array, false);
```

And the **menu.php** file (An php array instead of plane text stored in the .txt file) :

```
<?PHP

$menu_array = Array(
            'Main Page 1' => "page_1.php",
            'Main Page 2' => Array("Sub Page 1" => "sub_page_1.php", "Sub Page 2" => "sub_page_2.php"),
            'Main Page 3' => Array('Sub Page 1' => Array("Sub Sub Page 1" => "sub_sub_page_1.php", "Sub Sub Page 2" => "sub_sub_page_2.php"), 'Sub Page 2' => "#"),
            'Main Page 4' => "page_4.php"
        );

?>
```

This works pretty well. It's basically a result of conglomeration of code found over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery instead. So, maybe this code snippet can help you to solve your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    var filename = pathname.substr(pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

    if( ! filename)
    {
        filename = "index.php";
    }

    $("ul.navigation > li > a").each(function(){

        if($(this).attr("href") == filename || $(this).next("ul").find("a[href='"+filename+"']").length > 0)
        {
            $(this).addClass("current");
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Tried, but not works for me. Of course I've replaced "yourMenuClass" to "navigation" which is the class name of my menu... Thanks.

Comment: How does look your real sub-menu links? Is there just PHP files or GET parameters, or anything else?

Comment: Only php files, like "index.php", "page1.php", "sub_page1.php"... However, the code above would highlight a very first menu item containing the current page? Or just current page or its parent? I need this to highlight a very first menu item, even if the current page is really deep in the menu. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my code - check it out! Now it highlights only first level menu link! I tested the script and it works for me!

Comment: No matter how hard I try, I can't get it works :( . What is the: `ul.navigation` in your code exactly? My menu is begining with: `<div id="menu" > <ul id="navigation">
      <li> <a href="index.php">Home</a> ...` and so on...

Comment: It looks like the UL in your HTML has id="navigation", but in my code the UL has a class="navigation". So update jQuery selector to this one - `$("#navigation > li > a").each(function(){...`